# Where can I find the relationship between an Act Of Parliament and the Bill that was passed to create or amend it?

Tags: united-kingdom, law, parliament

I see that the UK has [bills before parliament](http://services.parliament.uk/bills/?group=date&order=desc), and in the case that they are given Royal Assent they become [Acts of Parliament](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/).

However, what I can't find is the relationship between the two. Where can I find the Act and the history of bills that have created and/or modified it online?

Comment: Loosely related: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9790/how-to-find-house-of-commons-debates-for-a-particular-act

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the information on the [publications](http://www.parliament.uk/business/bills-and-legislation/) section of the Parliament website is very limited. But, you'll be able to easily point yourself to the correct Act corresponding to the correct Bill, if you refine your search.

So, how I'm going to explain it, is a slow process and just an example. I can assume you'd only want to research specific Bills/Acts and not have an archive of the relationships between the two displayed in front of you (if so, you'd have to individually research and document an archive yourself as I can't find that much information regarding the relationships either (maybe something worth coding)).

### The Process

1. Go to the publications section of the parliament website
2. Click the hyperlink to "[Bills in previous sessions](http://www.parliament.uk/business/bills-and-legislation/current-bills/previous-bills/)"
3. Then you'll have several options to refine your search even further, you'll be given the option to select the year that session was held and a type of Bill you would like to search for (e.g. private/public)
4. Let's say I want to find a [Private Bill before Parliament in the session of 2003-04](http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm200304/privbill.htm)
5. I would then select the bill I'm researching, in this case it would be: Ipswich Market Bill
6. The website provides a link to the Act via the description "*This bill has received Royal Assent and the Act can be found on [Her Majesty's Stationery Office site](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga)*"
7. So all you need to do now is refine your search on that website, so for this case it would be: "Ipswich Market" in the title section of the search bar. 
   [image]
8. The results came back with one act. "[Ipswich Market Act 2004](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukla/2004/3/contents/enacted)"

This is the only way I have found so far. Unfortunately, there's not really a history per say but you can look further into the Bill itself (i.e. on the website it'll tell you the process it took, such as it ran [unopposed in the House of Commons Bills Committee](http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm/cmimweb.htm) for example), now you know what Act it belongs to you can look further into the relationship between the two.

**Note**: Not all bills will have a corresponding name to the Act, this is just a generalized form of linking both the Bill to the Act.

Comment: This is a great help, thanks. I'm pondering on a project which will unite data from a couple of sources and this links the act and the bills nicely. https://github.com/TheMightyLlama/UKBills